# how to configure regex for dns enum lookup?

Tags: linux, enums, dns, bind9

Here is my zone file:

```
$TTL 1H
@       IN      SOA     ns.e164.arpa.   hostmaster.e164.arpa. (
                        199802151       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        8H              ; refresh, seconds
                        2H              ; retry, seconds
                        4W              ; expire, seconds
                        1D )            ; minimum, seconds
;
                NS      ns              ; Inet Address of name server
;
;
2.8.0.2.0.8.0.0.8.5.6.1.9.4.e164.arpa. NAPTR 0 0 "u" "E2U+sip" "!^.*$!sip:+49165800802082@ibcf.core.test;user=phone!" .

2.8.0.2.0.8.0.0.8.5.6.1.9.4.e164.arpa. NAPTR 0 0 "u" "E2U+sip" "!^.*$!sip:+49165800802082@ibcf.core.test!" .

3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa.       NAPTR 0 0 "u" "E2U+pstn:tel" "!^.*$!tel:+1-215-555-0123;npdi;rn=+1-215-555-0199!" .

3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa.       NAPTR 10 100 "u" "E2U+pstn:sip" "!^.*$!sip:+1-215-555-0123;npdi;rn=+1-215-555-0199@ibcf.core.test;user=phone!".
;
;
; A records:
;
ns              A       10.10.240.4
localhost       A       127.0.0.1
ns              AAAA    3001:10:240::4
```

Then i run:

```
dig naptr 3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa @127.0.0.1
```

it works ok, the result is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2 <<>> naptr 3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40018
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa. IN    NAPTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa. 3600 IN NAPTR  10 100 "u" "E2U+pstn:sip" "!^.*$!sip:+1-215-555-0123\;npdi\;rn=+1-215-555-0199@ibcf.core.test\;user=phone!" .
3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa. 3600 IN NAPTR  0 0 "u" "E2U+pstn:tel" "!^.*$!tel:+1-215-555-0123\;npdi\;rn=+1-215-555-0199!" .

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
e164.arpa.      3600    IN  NS  ns.e164.arpa.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.e164.arpa.       3600    IN  A   10.10.240.4
ns.e164.arpa.       3600    IN  AAAA    3001:10:240::4

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 19 10:42:20 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 313
```

***My Question:***

I have a lot of address like (`3.2.1.0.5.5.5.5.1.2.1.e164.arpa.`) to lookup, but i don't want write every record in this zone file.

Do dns support regex for zone configure file?
just like:

```
3.*.e164.arpa.       NAPTR 10 100 "u" "E2U+pstn:sip" "!^.*$!sip:+1-215-555-0123;npdi;rn=+1-215-555-0199@ibcf.core.test;user=phone!".
```

The first char is `3` will match this rule.